# Unable to connect to Bitnami Cassandra container from cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, docker

I am very new to `cassandra` I am trying to bring up `cassnadra` using `docker-compose` but it is giving connection error for `cqlsh`. Can you please let me know what am I missing here and how can I run `init.cql` script when cassandra up, I tried with volume but not working -

```
  cassandra:
    image: bitnami/cassandra
    ports:
      - '9042:9042' # native protocol clients
    volumes:
      - 'cassandra_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_USER=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASS=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_CQL_PORT_NUMBER=9042
```

I can see logs in docker -

```
cassandra 05:12:49.12 
cassandra 05:12:49.12 Welcome to the Bitnami cassandra container
cassandra 05:12:49.13 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com /bitnami/containers
cassandra 05:12:49.13 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami  /containers/issues
cassandra 05:12:49.14 
cassandra 05:12:49.15 INFO  ==> ** Starting Cassandra setup **
cassandra 05:12:49.19 WARN  ==> CASSANDRA_HOST not set, defaulting to system hostname
cassandra 05:12:49.21 INFO  ==> Validating settings in CASSANDRA_* env vars..
cassandra 05:12:49.22 WARN  ==> You've not provided a password. Default password    "cassandra" will be used. For safety reasons, please provide a secure password in a  production environment.
cassandra 05:12:49.23 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable        CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra. This is the default value when bootstrapping Cassandra and    should not be used in production environments.
cassandra 05:12:49.40 INFO  ==> Initializing Cassandra database...
cassandra 05:12:50.22 INFO  ==> Deploying Cassandra from scratch
cassandra 05:12:50.22 INFO  ==> Starting Cassandra
cassandra 05:12:50.23 INFO  ==> Checking that it started up correctly
cassandra 05:14:10.63 INFO  ==> Found CQL startup log line
cassandra 05:14:12.41 INFO  ==> Nodetool reported the successful startup of Cassandra
cassandra 05:14:12.41 INFO  ==> Non-seeder node. Waiting for synchronization
cassandra 05:14:12.41 INFO  ==> Trying to access CQL server @ 6b7f5635c6cc
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you please provide the replication steps? You need to provide background info when asking questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have any issues connecting to a Cassandra container running the Bitnami image.

You didn't provide details of what your issue was or steps to replicate the problems so I'm going to provide the steps I did in the hope that it will help you.

**STEP 1** - Pull the Bitnami Cassandra Docker image:

```
$ docker pull bitnami/cassandra:latest
```

**STEP 2** - Create a bridged network called `cass-network`:

```
$ docker network create cass-network --driver bridge
```

**STEP 3** - Launch the Cassandra instance called `bitnamicassandra`:

```
$ docker run --rm -d \
    --name bitnamicassandra \
    -p 9042:9042 \
    --hostname bitnamicassandra \
    --network cass-network \
    bitnami/cassandra
```

**STEP 4** - Connect to the container to watch the Cassandra `system.log` and wait for startup to complete, specifically waiting for the node to listen for CQL connections:

```
INFO  [main] 2023-02-10 05:45:01,138 PipelineConfigurator.java:126 - \
    Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...
```

Since I've exposed the CQL port (with `--port 9042:9042`), I can see on my Docker host that the port is mapped as I expected:

```
$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN | grep dock
com.docke 51936          erick   85u  IPv6 0xddbfea4aa7f1e44f      0t0  TCP *:9042 (LISTEN)
com.docke 51969          erick   21u  IPv4 0xddbfea4ba2125bef      0t0 ICMP *:*
```

NOTE: You can also use the Linux command `netstat -tnlp`.

**STEP 5** - Connect to Cassandra using cqlsh:

```
$ cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connected to My Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.1.0 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>
```

If you update your original question with:

- steps to replicate your issue,
- full command you ran, and
- full error message,

I'd be happy to review it.

For more info + examples, see the [Bitnami Cassandra image page on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/cassandra/). Cheers!